# Visual Studio 2010, error when including headers from another folder within the same solution space

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am new to `Visual Studio 10 c++`, I imported a sample project, the project came with multiple folders in the same solution space project, each with files in it, `including` any of those files in any other file within any of the project worked perfectly then I added another filter to the project, it worked fine but the files in it can not be `included` in any of the original project files, is there anything am missing out? I followed these instructions when creating the folder

1. Right Click project
2. Click Add
3. Select `New Filter`
4. change Filter Name
5. Right Click Filter
6. Add
7. Select `Class`

And could someone tell me how to make the `Filters` and file in them visible in explore, the Sample project came with `Visible` `Filters/Folders` so there has to be a way of making them visible in explore and `VS`, here are Images showing what I mean, in the project I have the `laneDetector` filter which does not exist in project folder

[Showing My VS project layout with LaneDetector filter/folder visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ki6K.png)
[Showing My VS project in explore with no LaneDetector filter/folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fc5HY.png)

Comment: Visual Studio the post says

Comment: sorry they are suggestions by stack, I did not notice that